# How to know when TTS is finished?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm implementing an Interactive Voice Response application on Android. I would like to know how to determine when the `tts.speak()` function has done talking so I can call my speech recognizer function.

Comment: you can check this answer this is working for me
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17921775/1355195

Comment: you can visit this website: https://dev.to/charfaouiyounes/make-your-android-apps-talk-with-text-to-speech-1no8 to see more information about TTS

Comment: Don't forget to setup `utteranceId`. Without this id listener is not called. `textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "utteranceId")`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
public class TTSActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener, ... {
private TextToSpeech mTts;
...........
private void speak(String text) {
   if(text != null) {
      HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
      myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
      myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
      mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
   }
}
// Fired after TTS initialization
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    }
}
// It's callback
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
   Log.i(TAG, utteranceId); //utteranceId == "SOME MESSAGE"
   }
...........
}
```

**Read** [A good tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

Comment: one question, why does the onUtteranceCompleted() method doesn't get called? I'm trying to do it and I cannot get it fired. Thanks.

Comment: This method is fired when the finished sound synthesis. This is callback method.So you don't need call this method. It's a listener

Comment: Now `OnUtteranceProgress` is suggested instead of `OnUtteranceCompleted`

Comment: @mysuperass can you tell me how can i determine single word in tts i want to display each single word which is being speaking.

Answer (score 26):

The setOnUtteranceCompletedListener is deprecated since API level 15. Instead, use [setOnUtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceProgressListener(android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener)).

I found a code snippet ([here](http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbd34da0ae25e0f855408/android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech?tag=dragonfly)) that made it really easy for me to know when text to speech is finished:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                // Log.d("MainActivity", "TTS finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}
```

http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbd34da0ae25e0f855408/android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech?tag=dragonfly

Answer (score 8):

To know when TTS is finished you have to call the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` which has 3 call back methods `onStart`,`onDone` and `onError`
then include a Utterance Id to the speak method

Code Snippet

```
textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            int result=textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                Log.i("TextToSpeech","Language Not Supported");
            }

            textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Done");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Error");
                }
            });

        }else {
            Log.i("TextToSpeech","Initialization Failed");
        }
    }
});


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that there are people having problems in the use of TextToSpeech to ask that the solution to you

How to know when TTS is finished? 
without use setOnUtteranceCompletedListener

```
public void isTTSSpeaking(){

    final Handler h =new Handler();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                onTTSSpeechFinished();
            }

            h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    h.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this following code which shows a toast after TTS completed. Replace toast with your own action.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{


private boolean initialized;
private String queuedText;
private String TAG = "TTS";
private TextToSpeech tts;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    tts = new TextToSpeech(this /* context */, this /* listener */);
    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mProgressListener);


    speak("hello world");

}




public void speak(String text) {

    if (!initialized) {
        queuedText = text;
        return;
    }
    queuedText = null;

    setTtsListener(); // no longer creates a new UtteranceProgressListener each time
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);
}


private void setTtsListener() {

}





@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        initialized = true;
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

        if (queuedText != null) {
            speak(queuedText);
        }
    }
}



private abstract class runnable implements Runnable {
}




private UtteranceProgressListener mProgressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
    } // Do nothing

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
    } // Do nothing.

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();

    }
}; }
```

Comment: This works for me. OnDone method of TTS Listerner need runOnUIThred to show case popup, dialogs, toast on UI.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I solved the problem. I wanted the start button to stay lit as long as someone was speaking. Maybe this will help someone.

```
    public void _tts_speak_lenght() {
    t2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (TTS.isSpeaking()) {
                        isSpeaking = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (!TTS.isSpeaking()) {
                            t2.cancel();
                            isSpeaking = false;
                            imgBtn_startReader.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_start_off);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t2, (int)(0), (int)(100));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this listener :

```
    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(
        object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    //if you want update ui you should use handler
                }
            }

            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    //if you want update ui you should use handler
                }
            }

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    //if you want update ui you should use handler
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

use a  SpeakableListener when do text to speak.

```
private volatile boolean finished;

private SpeakableListener listener = new SpeakableListener() {

    @Override
    public void markerReached(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void speakableCancelled(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void speakableEnded(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        TestSpeaker.this.finished = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void speakablePaused(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void speakableResumed(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void speakableStarted(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        TestSpeaker.this.finished = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void topOfQueue(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void wordStarted(SpeakableEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

/** Speak the following string. */
public void sayIt(String str) {
    System.out.print(" " + str + " ");
    /* The the synthesizer to speak. */
    synthesizer.speakPlainText(str, listener);
```

Comment: what are you talking about? what SpeakableListener?

Comment: how to use SpeakableListener ?

Comment: this is not available in Android