# Android Text to speech And Speech to text

Tags: android

I am working with text to speech and speech to text at the same time. I am making an app in which it ask a question through text to speech and get the answer from the user through speech and app convert it to text. but it does not work fine. both are working at the same time like what it speak, it text it back. can we give some delay so that when it stop speaking then it listen for the voice and return that text.
`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implementsTextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    TextView eText1;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    String speech = "Hey, Can u read me?";
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        eText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                       .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    eText1.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, speech);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void speakOut() {
        String text = speech;
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA){
                Toast.makeText(this, "This language is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                speakOut();
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @TameHog if there is any mistake in my code please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
speakOut();
promptSpeechInput();
```

to

```
promptSpeechInput();
```

And then add:

```
speakOut();
```

after

```
eText1.setText(result.get(0));
```

This should speak the text after it has finished getting the text

Edit: use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658376/how-to-know-when-tts-is-finished) to determine when the speech is finished. When it is just call promptSpeechInput()

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry its late I've been busy lately

Comment: onStart() and onDone() methods doesn't call at all :(