# TextToSpeech API

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In Android TextToSpeech, How come we know either Speech is finished. I want to change icon after speech finished. I declared tts.speak() in Button Onclick Listener. i used thread postdelayed handler to change icon after some time. but the text to read changes different at different times.It didnt worked out. CheckThemestart(),ChangeThemeStop() are functions to change the icon.

i declared the following in OnCreate()  :

```
            tts = new TextToSpeech(getContext(), new 
                         TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
           @Override
           public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            tts.speak("",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
```

Button-onClickListener :

```
 if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    CheckThemeStart();
                    tts.speak(plainText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             //change icon after spoken
                            CheckThemeStop();

                        }
                    }, 15000);

                } else {
                    CheckThemeStop();
                    tts.stop();
                }
```

Comment: did you try setOnUtteranceProgressListener ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when TTS is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658376/how-to-know-when-tts-is-finished)

Comment: i tried with setOnUtterenceProgressListener. but it didnt worked out, i declared  the below next to tts.speak():                                                                     
           tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new 
          TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
        CheckThemeStop();
       }
      })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we declare a hasmap parameter with unique string ID and pass that id to compare utterence id if matches it execute what you declare inside onUtterenceCompletedListener().
The following is code snippet.

```
                    HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"SpeakID");
                    tts.speak(plainText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,params);
                    tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                            if(utteranceId.equals("SpeakID"))
                            {
                                    CheckThemeStop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register `UtteranceProgressListener` for tts start and end times and error handling.

```
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) {

        }
      });
```

Comment: I tried this also by declaring speak() in onStart() and change icon in OnDone(). but both of them is not working

Comment: Please put the logs and debugged and check if they are getting called or not? or else put the whole code ofTTS.

Comment: @ReyanshMishra i checked in debugger. It didnt entered inside onStart(),onDone(). i also tried with setOnUtterenceCompletedListener(). that too not worked.

Comment: @RagavendraM Can you listen sound ?

Comment: @kimkevin i didnt hear when i declared inside onStart().