# Flutter text-to-speech (Dart language): How to add a background color to a text while the tts engine is reading it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, text-to-speech, google-apps

I wanna create something like that in Dart code, NOT in Java:

[image: while tts engine reads the text, a background color follows it]

While tts engine reads some text, a background color follows it helping the reader. It's much more than THAT another question you answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when TTS is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658376/how-to-know-when-tts-is-finished)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I guess you didn't pay attention to my question. I said Dart language and you Style-7 show us a Java example.

Comment: No, my question doesn't have an answer here: How to know when TTS is finished?

Answer (score -1):

1.

```
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put( TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "stringId" );
                tts.speak( text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params );
```

2.

```
                if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15 ){
                    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener( new UtteranceProgressListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onStart( String s ){
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDone( String s ){
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError( String s ){
                        }
                    } );
                }else{
                    tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener( new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onUtteranceCompleted( String s ){
                        }
                    } );
                }
```